# MYSQL database problem with LENGTH(CONCAT)

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have problem with quite simple example.

I want from the table, list all information about people whose name and
last name is more than 10 characters.

I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE LENGTH(CONCAT(name, forname)) > 10;
```

But it will write me the whole table instead of the last name and first name with a length> 10

Comment: I would check that you have some rows with those fields concatentated > 10 as that works

Comment: There is [nothing wrong](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a8426cf5ccd7840a11acaa38c83ef31) with your SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

If your data stored like [this variation of many white spaces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=518923616fdc815f8cc0261dd4db0d5e), then you can try using [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to remove leading/trailing white spaces:

```
SELECT *
FROM name_of_table
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(CONCAT(NAME, forename))) > 10;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22cefd7092643a062dc5382a926ffc44)